# How can I make downloaded files appear in “Recent” in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder

I'd like files downloaded via browser to also appear in "Recent" in Finder, as well as the normal content there. I really miss this functionality from Ubuntu and am aware of how much time and clicks it costs to not have it. How can that be achieved?

Comment: They show up in the Downloads folder, would this help?

Comment: In macOS High Sierra, I see things I've downloaded in Safari in Recents in Finder. What version of macOS are you running?

Comment: How do I tell? I use Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Go to the Apple Menu and select "About this Mac..." The first window gives you OS version and basic Mac hardware info. Other tabs will give you the whole enchilada.

Comment: One approach is to open Finder -> Settings -> Sidebar and make sure "Recents" is checked. I see some downloads in mine - although I have a script that grabs newly downloaded items and moves them to dated folders, so maybe they show up in Sidebar Recents because they've been handled by that script.

Comment: Perhaps there is a macOS "defaults write xxx" setting that would add a Downloads section to the Apple Menu -> Recents menu ...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but I found out how to fix it.

Go to the Downloads folder, and on the menu bar above, click **View**, and then click **Show View Options**. Finally, on the **Sort By** section, select **Date Added**.

[image: Here's some screenshots]

Comment: This sorts the downloads folder by recently added, it doesn't surface these items in the recents screen